# Error when executing transfer with sufficient funds

Tags: solidity, remix, wallet-transfer

When executing a function which buys a loan from a portfolio (sellPortfolio in the code here), I get the following error:

[image]

I am using Remix 0.5.2 and I have tried to run this from the Java front-end as well as directly from Remix. I checked that there were enough funds for the transfer. I also use exactly the same syntax in another function/contract which works fine.

```
function buyLoan(Loan _sellLoan, Portfolio _sellPortfolio, uint _tradePrice) public {

            uint tradePrice = _tradePrice;

            // Get Sell Portfolio for transfer
            Portfolio sp = _sellPortfolio;

            // Now send funds
            address(sp).transfer(tradePrice);    

            // Add loan to portfolio
            _sellLoan.setPrice(tradePrice);
            loans.push(Loan(_sellLoan)) -1;
            portfolioLoanBalance += _sellLoan.getBalance();

            // Now add loan to buying portfolio - "A"=Active=0x41 / "I"=Inactive=0x49 / "S"=Sold=0x53  
            portfolioLoanStatus[address(_sellLoan)] = 0x41;

            // Delete loan from selling portfolio
            sp.setLoanStatus(_sellLoan, 0x53);

        } // function buyLoan(Loan _sellLoan, Portfolio _sellPortfolio) public
```

and here is the fallback function for Portfolio:

```
function () payable external {
    // fallback function to receive funds
    received = msg.value;
    availableFunds += received;
    } // function () payable external {
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without seeing (the rest of) your code. What is `Portfolio`? What's in its fallback function? Can that fallback function accept ether? Can it execute successfully with only 2300 gas? Does it have any `require` statements? Are you satisfying those requirements in this call?

Comment: I just noticed there's also an ellipsis... did you omit some of the code in `buyLoan`?

Comment: Thanks Smarx. I have added the missing code and fallback function. I will add that if I take out the transfer statement, the function works and does what it should do.

Comment: `address.transfer()` only gives the recipient 2300 gas, but `Portfolio`'s fallback function looks like it requires more than that due to writing to storage. Does the problem go away if you use `address(sp).call.value(tradePrice)()`? If so, gas was the problem. But it's also possible for `_sellLoan.setPrice` to be failing or `sp.setLoanStatus`... a good way to figure out what's failing is just to delete things until the problem goes away.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just saw that if you remove the call to `transfer` things work. In that case, I'm fairly confident it is indeed a gas issue.

Comment: When I try address(sp).call.value(tradePrice)() I get a compile error that 0 arguments are given and expect 1. Is that the correct syntax?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Per https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes, you need to use `address(sp).call.value(tradePrice)("")`.

Comment: Thank-you Smarx! That solves the problem! If you enter an answer I will give you credit for it... Thanks again! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @PhilipRutovitz I've to point that using `call` you can be subject to reentrancy attacks if `_sellPortfolio` is under the control of the user.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for your comment. What exactly is a reentrancy attack? How can I avoid the risk? Is there a better function to use? Thanks!

Comment: You can start with the documentation in solidity https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/security-considerations.html#re-entrancy, but if you search you will find more documentation.